# how to make a heat map when I have 2 conditions, each of which are in triplicate?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a heatmap using ggplot. My actual data is huge. But in this example, I can not get ggplot to 1) plot this and 2) plot condition "A" and "B" in parallel with each other (side-by-side on the same graph)

I have tried using dpyr's gather() to define "x" and "y" for the heat map but get this response:

```
          key value
1   condition    A1
2   condition    A1
3   condition    A1
4   condition    A2
5   condition    A2
6   condition    A2
...
...
...
32 expression     5
33 expression     6
34 expression     7
35 expression     8
36 expression     9

library(tidyverse)
```

## sample data 1

```
Matrix1 <- data.matrix(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3,
dimnames = list(c('AC009234.1' , 'ACSL5' , 'ADAMTS15')), byrow = FALSE))
```

## sample data 2

```
Matrix2 <-data.matrix(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3,
dimnames = list(c('AC009234.1' , 'ACSL5' , 'ADAMTS15')), byrow = FALSE))
```

## head sample datasets

```
df_1 <- `colnames<-`(Matrix1, c("A1", "A2", "A3"))
df_2 <- `colnames<-`(Matrix2, c("B1", "B2", "B3"))
```

## combine datasets and convery to dataframe

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(df_1, df_2))
```

## Trying x and values

```
mydata <- gather(data, key = condition, value = expression)
```

## sample plot

```
p <- (ggplot(mydata, aes(Condition, expression, fill = expression)) 
      + geom_tile(aes(fill = expression), colour = "white")
      + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red"))
p
```

there should be 2 keys, to my understanding, condition "A" and "B". And I need the conditions to be on the x axis on the heatmap plot. THANK YOU in advance!

Comment: Following your instructions, I get `mydata <- structure(list(condition = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A3", "A3", "A3", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", 
"B3"), expression = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")`, which has 6 conditions A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, relating to the original 6 columns in `data`.

Comment: Presumably you meant `aes(condition,` and not `aes(Condition,`?

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, I think the last missing step is to extract the letter from the `condition` field which has 6 values based on the `data` columns (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3).

```
mydata %>%
  separate(condition, c("condition", "version"), -1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(condition, expression, fill = expression)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = expression), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: A and B each represent 3 samples from different animals. The heatmap needs to have 6 columns in this example.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with your original code, aside from `condition` being capitalized `Condition` in your plot call.

Comment: I figured it out. ggplot is unable to plot multiple heat maps in parallel. Bioconductor has a package called ComplexHeatmap that does plot heatmaps in parallel, and much more. Thank you for your time though.